# I have a "D-type" German student visa. Is it possible to study in Finland and get the residence permit for Finland?

Tags: germany, schengen, study, finland, pakistani-citizen

Being an international (Pakistani) Postgraduate student, I have just received my German study visa “Type D” (for 90days). I will be coming to Germany in start of August.

Then I applied for another master's degree program which is an exchange student program where I have to study for the first 2 semesters in Helsinki (Finland) and the last two in Berlin (although the degree will be awarded by the German University).

Is it possible that after comming to Germany rather than getting enrolled in the university for which I was granted visa I move to that exchange program where I have to study in Finland for first 2 semesters?

Can I apply for student residence permit by travelling to Finland from Germany immediately after landing in Germany as I have a valid Schengen visa to enter Finland?

Is it possible that after entering into the Finland I can apply and obtain a one year residence permit for my exchange program?

Comment: [This page](http://www.studyinfinland.fi/living_in_finland/before_your_arrival/residence_permits) seems to suggest that it's not possible to apply from within the country (such rules are not uncommon). Besides, doing it that way seems to invite a lot of problems. You won't have time to do it before the beginning of August but you should really apply for a residence permit from the Finnish embassy instead. You also want to be careful not to give the impression that you misused your German visa, especially considering the fact that you will need another one for the last two semesters in Berlin.

Comment: For what purpose did you get your German visa? Will you study in Germany starting from August? If yes, then how long? When does your exchange student program starts? Btw, the D-type visa does not allow you to travel to Finland.

Comment: Please see a similar question: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19262/13223